# Objective-C: How to hold the thread until the NSSheet is closed?

Tags: objective-c

I am opening an NSWindow as NSSheet and I want to hold the thread until the NSSheet is closed.

```
    _license =  [[LicenseArgWindow alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"LicenseArgWindow"];

    [self.window beginSheet:self.license.window  completionHandler:^(NSModalResponse returnCode) {}];

    [NSApp beginSheet: _license
       modalForWindow: _window
        modalDelegate: self
       didEndSelector: nil
          contextInfo: nil];   


///here is the problem 
///the thread reaches here wheather the nswindow is closed or not
BOOL isAgreed = _license.isAgreed;
```

**How to stop the thread at NSSheet launch and the thread should not pass until the NSWindow is closed**

Please help. Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `didEndSelector` parameter in:

```
[NSApp beginSheet: _license
           modalForWindow: _window
            modalDelegate: self
           didEndSelector: @selector(didEndSheet:returnCode:contextInfo:)
              contextInfo: nil];
```

and have that do the "accepted license" bit:

```
- (void)didEndSheet:(NSWindow *)sheet
         returnCode:(NSInteger)returnCode
        contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo
{
    [sheet orderOut:self];
    BOOL isAgreed = _license.isAgreed;
}
```

[Here is a guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Sheets/Tasks/UsingCustomSheets.html) from Apple.

Comment: Your answer is cool and I am going to do the same but can not I just Hold the thread?

Comment: You don't hold the thread as Cocoa is an event-based system.  You let it continue into the runloop and you pick-up execution again in the selector defined by `didEndSelector`.

Comment: @VikasBansal Actually I cannot even see that version of `beginSheet` in the documentation.  Are you sure it's not deprecated?

Comment: I do not know much about Cocoa as I am 4 months old. It would be really kind if let me know what should I do if beginSheet is deprecated. I want to show a window as Popup that Breaks user communication with the main window. NSSheet was that I get on the internet. @trojanfoe many thanks

Comment: I think it's just that version of the call; the only version I saw uses an completion block, which is the more modern way of doing such things.

Comment: Sir @trojanfoe, please elaborate.

Comment: Don't worry about it.  If the version you show in your code works then just use that, but specify the end selector.  This is where I was unable to determine what the end selector signature looked like as I couldn't see it in the docs.

Comment: I am passing a selector as you said but it is not being called. Please help Sir

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of sheets is that they are modal **for just the one window**. The rest of the app has to continue to function. The user can work with other windows or do global actions like open a new file, etc. To block the whole app's execution waiting for the sheet is entirely against the purpose of sheets as a UI mechanism.

If you want an app-modal dialog, run the dialog as a modal window (not sheet). You can either use an `NSAlert` which has a `runModal` method, or you can use an arbitrary window using `-[NSApplication runModalForWindow:]`.